# Bsc on and off sells contract

Tags: solidity, bsc

Hello can someone expl how to switch on and off selling bsc tokens in solidity. I want to make legit coin but i need this to my idea. Thanks for help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent from transferring tokens to any address (which would stop buying, selling and transferring to contracts/EOAs) by doing something like this

```
bool isPaused = 0 
function pauseOrUnPause(bool _isPaused) {
isPaused = _isPaused;
}
```

then adding `require(!isPaused)` in your `_transfer` (the internal one that is called by `transfer` and `transferFrom`) function.

Blocking only sells is a bit trickier, you would need to do something like that

```
if(isPaused && _to == uniswapV2PairAddress) {
revert('selling turned off')
}
else {
//your transfer logic
}
}
```

Comment: the 2nd can be worked around by creating a new pair though, although it's likely to have very low liquidity. (also a "legit" coin shouldnt prevent its users from trading it freely...)